# Is my index page too large?

Tags: optimization, bandwidth, filesize

I'm developing a site right now that I've been working on for more than a year. Today, I am about one week from launching so I started going over things that I've not gone over during the last year - including loading-times. I've not noticed any loading-issues, but I still wanted to look.

The following represents my index page:

```
Documents (1 file)       22 KB
Images (53 files)        96 KB
Objects (0 files)   
Scripts (9 files)        90 KB - Including jQuery.min.js
Style Sheets (6 files)   23 KB
-------------------------------
                Total   230 KB
```

We no longer live in the world of 56k's and 28.8's, but I'm wondering what should be considered too large now today. I should mention also that Analytics reports 3.28% of my visitors having dial-up. These users currently browse an index page that is 158kb in size.

Other interesting index page sizes:

- Google: 20kb
- Amazon: 525kb
- StackOverflow: 121kb
- Digg: 58kb
- Revision3: 936kb

Comment: Have you already shrinked the images as much as you could? PNG and color-reduction are your friends. But after all: that is what caches are for after the first load :)

Comment: PS: I mention pictures, because sending all of them through a automated conversions and comparing them to the version is the cheapest optimization I'd try. Especially with them being a third of all the load.

Comment: @Leonida, I have optimized my larger images. I had one .png that was 50kb. It's now about 9kb. I do want to attempt some sprites later though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but the [Yahoo! Exceptional Performance](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/) web site is packed with articles and tips on front-end engineering issues such as these, which can affect the user perception of site load times.

In particular, I'd suggest that it might be possible to reduce the number of HTTP requests being made - six stylesheets and 59 images, for example - perhaps some of those images could be [sprited](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#opt_sprites) to reduce that figure?

Comment: I completely agree. Unfortunately the development-process was "Agile," and much of the layout was determined ad-hoc, sadly. I would like to go back and minify my .css files, join then when possible, and sprite multiple images when time permits.

Comment: Did you forget the refactoring part of "agile" development?

Comment: @webdtc - I'm the sole developer of this project, and the current is powered by upper-management. "Add something on there that contains X information" portrays the type of demands I get on a weekly (sometimes daily) basis :)

Comment: I didn't mean to be snide.  I find that most real projects can't follow ideal processes.  Still, this would be a good time to point out to upper-management that "Hey the page is huge partly due to the process"... if you wanted to :)  By the way I don't think the page is too big.

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty big, but I wouldn't consider it a problem until/unless it **becomes** a problem. Be wary of premature optimization in *any* context.